# Datagridview Search non SQL Search Button c#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

Currently I have a datagridview that is pulling data from a CRM server for all the information, and I was wondering if there was any way to have a search button that would be able to search with the LIKE function like searching an SQL database would allow. Right now my search button has to be exact text to find the row I want, and I was just hoping that if it's possible you guys would be able to help me. This is the code I have right now.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchValue = txtS.Text;
    int rowIndex = -1;
    dataTable.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
            {
                rowIndex = row.Index;
                dataTable.ClearSelection();
                row.Selected = true;
                dataTable.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowIndex;
                dataTable.Focus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No solutions with that name.");
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Regular expressions.

Comment: Or instead of .Equals() use .Contains()

Comment: @RyanWilson -- that doesn't really work if you have multiple wildcards.

Comment: @rory.ap I agree with you on that, but since the OP didn't really specify, I thought I'd throw out the possibility of using .Contains().

Comment: Use a DataView.Rowfilter